# get contacts and users from active directory group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm querying AD and getting all users from within a specific group. I now need to also get all contacts within those groups, but I'm having trouble finding contacts.

My AD connection:

`AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPath"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServiceAccount"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServiceAccountPassword"]);`

Getting all users within a group:

```
  GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Global.AD,((grpname.Length > 0)? grpname: "NY Directory Group"));
```

`foreach (Principal princ in @group.Members)//.Where(princ => princ.StructuralObjectClass == "user"))`

Originally I had the filter for princ.StructuralObjectClass which I removed to include objects other than "user", but I'm still only getting users.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace provides uniform access and manipulation of user, computer, and group **security principals** across the multiple principal stores like AD, LDS etc.

As contacts are not *security principal* you probably should use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace to deal with all non security objects.